# How to implement Rust Struct in TS tests?

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, anchor-test

Hi guys I have a struct in my Rust code that is used in a struct that is a account, my code :

```
#[account]
pub struct TournamentTwoPlayers {
    pub games: [Game; 1],
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone,Copy,Default)]
pub struct Game {
    ...
}

pub fn save_tournament_two_players(    ctx: Context<SaveTournamentTwoPlayers>,
    games: [Game; 1],...)
```

Now in the TS test code, I need to pass the Game as argument to my instruction how can I access Game class in the TS test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor TS will serialise objects into bytes that can then be deserialised properly by Borsh on your program side.

So for example, if you have this struct:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone,Copy,Default)]
pub struct Game {
    some_field: boolean,
    another_field: u64,
}
```

You can call it in Anchor TS like this:

```
await.program.methods
  .saveTournamentTwoPlayers({
    someField: true,
    anotherField: new BN(3),
  })
  .accounts({
    ...
  })
  .rpc()
```

Please take note of the camelCase format of the field names.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, But in this example, you are passing the primitive types to the instruction and I need to pass the Game model here, So my question is, is that possible?

Comment: In that example I'm passing a Game struct in, not primitives.